# How to display custom field on homepage

Tags: php, wp-query, customization, meta-query

I am new to custom fields thing. I am working on a movie review site. And wants to add movie story or plot field, I have successfully added the custom field named Story and its content is displaying on single.php. However, can I display same on index.php? Below is my code.

```
<?php 
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Story' );
if( !empty($meta) ) {
    echo $meta[0];
}?>
```

Comment: Please describe more "Story" is right name of meta. and whats u store in this field. this one array value stored?

Comment: Yes "Story" is my field name and yes array value stored.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'customField' ) ) :
function customField($name, $id=false, $single=false){
    global $post_type, $post;

    $name=trim($name);
    $prefix=''; // only if you need this
    $data=NULL;

    if($id!==false && !empty($id) && $id > 0)
        $getMeta=get_post_meta((int)$id, $prefix.$name, $single);
    else if(isset($post->ID) && $post->ID > 0)
        $getMeta=get_post_meta($post->ID,$prefix.$name, $single);
    else if('page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ))
        $getMeta=get_post_meta(get_option( 'page_for_posts' ),$prefix.$name, $single);
    else if(is_home() || is_front_page() || get_queried_object_id() > 0)
        $getMeta=get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(),$prefix.$name, $single);
    else
        $getMeta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),$prefix.$name, $single);

    if(isset($getMeta[0])) $data=$getMeta[0];

    if($data===false || !is_numeric($data) && (empty($data) || is_null($data))) return NULL;

    $return = preg_replace(array('%<p>(<img .*?/>)</p>%i','%<p>&nbsp;</p>%i','/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*/i'), array('$1','',''),$data);

    return (!empty($return)?$return:NULL);
}
endif;


echo customField("story"); // Default
echo customField("story", 55); // With custom page ID
```

This code work great becouse I build this for my works. If return empty, in place where you setup pharameters, you not save your data. Also be careful about prefix of your metabox if you use it.

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Are you save data in metabox?

Comment: Yes i did saved the data.

Comment: I know is old post but I just made update. This code search deeply inside WP and get custom field value on any place inside theme. I just have the same issue and find this working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on content.php because of index.php content comes from this file.

```
if u call outside of post use 
global $post;  
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID , 'Story', true);

OR inner loop

$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'Story', true);

if( !empty($meta) ) {
    echo $meta[0];
}
```

Comment: Not working, i have already tried this.